# Difference in difference papers that look at multiple cohorts at a point in time?

Tags: reference-request, difference-in-difference

I'm trying to see if a CCT targeted at school age children can mitigate adverse impact of weather shocks faced in childhood on their wages in adulthood (at age 30 say) using a setting similar to [Duflo,2001](https://economics.mit.edu/files/726).

However, unlike Duflo, the comparison I am trying to make is the following: a child from the earlier birth cohorts could have faced a weather shock at a certain age and not had access to the scheme, whereas a child from the latter birth cohorts could have faced weather shock at the same age but had exposure to the scheme.

However, I have not been able to find papers that use DiD for such age wise comparison using cross section data of multiple birth cohorts.
Would appreciate it if someone can direct me towards papers that can shed some light. Even some tangentially related DiD papers would do.

Thanks,
J